# View a pull request with Kaleidoscope

Tags: kaleidoscope

I would prefer to look at the contents of a pending github pull request in Kaleidoscope instead of the github UI.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

One solution that I've found, in the case where your PR is coming from a different branch on the same repo, is to pull down the branch and then run the following
`git difftool master..branch_name`